# Determine $a, b, c, d$, where $\int_0^x{\frac{t}{\arctan(t)}}dt=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+o(x^3)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $$f(x)=\int_0^x{\frac{t}{\arctan(t)}}dt=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+o(x^3)$$ be the function defined by the above integration where $x \not= 0$.

The exercise is to determine the constants $a, b, c, d$, but I was unable to develop the solution. The $o(x^3)$ is the o notation for the error in Taylor polynomials.

Comment: Do taylor expansion of $\arctan(t)$ in $t$, then take its reciprocal up to so many terms, then multiply by $t$ and integrate $0$ to $x$.

Comment: My problem is that the taylor expansion is around some $t$, but my $t$ varies from $0$ to $x$ in the integral.

Comment: Expand around $t$ in the integrand, then integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard series
$$\tan ^{-1}(t)=t-\frac{t^3}{3}+\frac{t^5}{5}+O\left(t^{7}\right)$$
$$\frac{t}{\tan ^{-1}(t)}=\frac {t} {t-\frac{t^3}{3}+\frac{t^5}{5}+O\left(t^{7}\right) }=\frac {1} {1-\frac{t^2}{3}+\frac{t^4}{5}+O\left(t^{6}\right) }$$
Use long division
$$\frac{t}{\tan ^{-1}(t)}=1+\frac{t^2}{3}-\frac{4 t^4}{45}+O\left(t^6\right)=1+\frac{t^2}{3}-\frac{4 t^4}{45}+O\left(t^6\right)$$
$$\int \frac{t}{\tan ^{-1}(t)}\,dt=t+\frac{t^3}{9}-\frac{4 t^5}{225}+O\left(t^{7}\right)$$ Remember that $\frac{t}{\tan ^{-1}(t)}$ is even and, so, the integral is odd; so the coefficients for even power of $t$ are zero.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Note that $a_n=\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$
$$a=f(0)$$
$$b=f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$$
$$c=\frac12f''(0)=\frac12\lim_{x\to0}f''(x)$$
and so on

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac t{\arctan t} = 1 + t + \frac 13t^2 + 0t^3 - \frac 4{45}t^4 + 0t^5 + O(t^6)$$
$$$$
$$\int_0^x {(1 + t + \frac 13t^2 + 0t^3 - \frac 4{45}t^4 + 0t^5)} dt$$ $$ = (t + \frac 12t^2 + \frac 1{3*3}t^3 + 0t^4 - \frac 4{45*5}t^5 + 0t^6)\bigg|_0^x$$ 
$$= 0 + x + 0x^2 + \frac19x^3 + 0x^4 -\frac 4{225}x^5$$

Answer (score 0):

Letting $x\to0$ gives $a=0$ since $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t}{\arctan t}=1$. Taking derivative for both sides gives
$$ x=\bigg[b+2cx+3dx^2+O(x^3)\bigg]\arctan x. $$
Using
$$ \arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+O\left(t^{7}\right) $$
one has
$$ x=\bigg[b+2cx+3dx^2+O(x^3)\bigg]\bigg[x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+O\left(t^{7}\right)\bigg]. $$
Comparing the coefficients of $x$, $x^2$ and $x^3$, respectively, one obtains
$$ b=1, c=0, -\frac b3+3d=0 $$
and hence
$$ a=0,b=1,c=0,d=\frac19. $$